# find keywords in a text using xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to write a stylesheet that highlights a keyword in a text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:param name="keyword">keyword</xsl:param>
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="element()">
                <xsl:variable name="elValue" select="."/>
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="upper-case(.)" regex="{upper-case($keyword)}*">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <i>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </i>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have used regular expressions.

My problem: the whole html-output is now in upper-case. I have tried to use the variable elValue to save the original value, but that does not work. The variable seems to append the new value in each loop (and does not only contain the new value).

Is there a way to output the original format of the elements (no upper case)?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete XML input sample and the HTML result you want to create with XSLT for that sample, then we can show the right XSLT approach. So far you have only shown some XSLT that does not do what you want, without allowing us to see the input you run it against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simply want to use an `i` flag on http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string i.e.

```
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$keyword}*" flags="i">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <i>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </i>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
```

Comment: Right approach - though I don't know what the "*" is supposed to be doing in the regex attribute.

Comment: The asterisk character was in the original code that I too did not completely understand so I simply edited the stuff doing the upper case conversion and retained everything else unchanged.